# JwPlayer: Get the Exact postition with getPosition()

Tags: jwplayer

I was able to alert the position of the video by using the jwplayer().getPosition() function but I get something like 3.6064999999999996 but the timer on the video showed me 03:36. How can I exactly get the position as 03:36 instead of 3.6064999999999996?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRfwx.png

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the fractional part and multiplying by 6 will give you the number of seconds.

Examples:  0.5 * 6 = 30,  0.6 * 6 = 36